# MySQL database schema: 3 columns of same type with different purpose

Tags: mysql

I am building a financial app, and it requires the following tables:

1. tax
2. item, which can have one tax
3. invoice, which can have many items

**To the question:**

An invoice must have the ability to contain 3 categories of emails:

1. Recipient emails
2. CC emails
3. BCC emails

So far I just have a recipients/cc/bcc column, but I don't think it's good because I'd basically have to concatenate the emails together and separate them by a comma or something.

I also thought about a generic email table, but then I'd have to create `invoice_recipient_email`, `invoice_cc_email` and `invoice_bcc_email` tables respectively, in order to link the emails back to the particular invoice ID as well as categorize them by the 3 types.

Can someone advice me on my second solution, or provide a better way to do this?

Here is my current schema:

```
CREATE TABLE tax (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    rate INT(3) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE item (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    quantity INT(10) NOT NULL,
    price INT(10) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT `f_tax_item_tax_id` FOREIGN KEY (`tax_id`) REFERENCES `tax` (`id`),

    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE invoice (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

    invoice_number VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    recipients VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    cc VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    bcc VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    discount INT(10) NOT NULL,
    note VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    terms VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL,
    due_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: you don't seem to have a field that shows how the invoice is for.  Do you not have a customers table?

Comment: Yes I have additional tables, this was just showing the tables relevant to the question. Also, the tables that show relationship from invoice to items 1:M isn't here either.

Comment: @JeffUK Hmm but wouldn't such an approach not scale very well? Granted, only so many email types can be added, but what if I kept having to add more columns to handle more email use cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a single recipients table with `id (pk), invoice_id (fk), email, recipient_type` fields, where recipient type could have one of the following values: to, cc, or bcc. The recipient type field would tell you how to use the email address, therefore you would not need 3 separate tables to hold the 3 different recipient types.

1 record would hold only 1 email address.

Comment: Hmm very nice, going to wait for a couple more answers and see if anyone comes up with anything else. I like this though!

Comment: @Lansana it's pretty much the same answer I was about to give; but I would've stipulated to stay away from defining the `recipient_type` as an enum (they're just more trouble than they are worth).

Comment: @Uueerdo I deliberately did not specify how to store the 3 values in my answer :) However,  to, cc, and bcc are the 3 standard recipient types for emails.

Comment: @Shadow yeah, not criticizing; just adding the small negligible difference our answers would have had.

Answer (score 1):

You can normalize your emails into a single table and put a flag on it to categorize its type.

```
CREATE TABLE invoice (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    invoice_number VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    discount INT(10) NOT NULL,
    note VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    terms VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL,
    due_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


CREATE TABLE email(
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    invoice_id INT(10)  not null references invoice(id),
    email_type int not null,
    addresses varchar(1000),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

You can define your email types in another table as well. You can look at this approach implemented in a production environment for phone numbers in MSSSQL but same concept. We however normalize the records to one phone number per record which I would also recommend you do.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ActorPhones](
    [PKId] [int] IDENTITY(0,1) NOT NULL Primary Key,
    [FKActorId] [int] NOT NULL References Actor(PKID),
    [FKPhoneTypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Number] [varchar](20) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PhoneTypes](
    [PKId] [int] IDENTITY(0,1) NOT NULL Primary Key,
    [PhoneTypeName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL References ActorPhones(PKId),
    [PhoneTypeDescription] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [varchar](50) NULL
)
```

Comment: I would not hold multiple email addresses in a single field.

Comment: shadow, why not? Semi-colon separated email strings are very common practice.  think of it as the CC string, not the CC email.

Comment: I agree, that is why added a real life of example of how we handle phone numbers.

Comment: What if you need to check for all records for an email address? Or you want to remove a single email address? There are many reasons to normalize your data.

Comment: @JeffUK acommon practice is not necessarily a good practice. Particularly not if you ever need to create a report showing who received what invoice. Also, with this solution you can only prevent in the application logic that the same email is added multiple time to the same invoice.

Comment: @shadow, theoretically, that's fine, but Sage, Oracle and Microsoft Dynamics all do it this way, so maybe it's good enough?  I don't know of many people who have more than 3 email addresses for invoicing!

Comment: @JeffUK this is an oversimplification of how these systems store email addresses.